# Area under $T$-$s$ diagram for an internally reversible process?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, entropy, reversibility

In Cengel and Boles, it is said that the area under a $T$-$s$ diagram for an internally reversible process is equal to the total heat transfer during the process.

The example given of an internally reversible process in the book is as follows:

[image]

Here, heat transfer occurs over a finite temperature difference producing a temperature gradient at the boundary between the system and surroundings. Entropy is generated at the boundary and passed to the system.

So:

$$ds = \frac{dq}{T} + ds_{irrev}$$

and $ds_{irrev} > 0$ due to this entropy generation.

If that is the case, then we can no longer say that $dq = T ds$, and $ q \neq \int T ds$

So, as far as I can see, the total heat transferred $q$ is not the area under a T-s diagram for this internally reversible process, which conflicts what is said in Cengel and Boles.

Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What do the two colors mean? What is the system? What do you mean by internal equilibrium on the right fugue?

Comment: (b) is not internally reversible.  Why do you think it is?

Comment: @ChetMiller I'm not too sure, but that's what the textbook says. Could you clarify what is meant by an internally reversible system/process?

Comment: @BobD The book doesn't really elaborate on the example and what the system is. Internal reversibility means no reversibility within the system boundaries, but I don't get how that is the case given that there is a temperature gradient on the boundary, and heat transfer across a finite temperature difference.

Comment: “Internal reversibility means no reversibility within the system boundaries”. That makes no sense.

Comment: @BobD Oh I'm sorry I meant no "irreversibility" within the system boundaries. "A process is called internally reversible if no irreversibilities occur within the boundaries of the system during the process" is the definition in Cengel and Boles

Comment: But the problem with fig b is the system is not in thermal equilibrium with the surroundings so the system cannot be in internal equilibrium thus it cannot be "internally reversible".  So it still makes no sense.

Comment: I'm really not sure to be honest. I am not very familiar with this terminology - that's just what the textbook says. In my course, we have only dealt with reversible/irreversible processes, but apparently the Rankine cycle is "internally reversible". So I am trying to understand exactly what that means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the integral, the temperature you are supposed to use is the boundary temperature (through which the heat flows), rather than the system temperature.  In this case, it is supposed to be 303 K, rather than 293 K.  So, $$\Delta S=\frac{Q}{293}$$ while, in case (b), the heat flow divided by the boundary temperature is $\frac{Q}{303}$.  So, $$\Delta S=\frac{Q}{293}=\frac{Q}{303}+S_{gen}$$. So the generated entropy is $$S_{gen}=\frac{Q}{293}-\frac{Q}{303}=\frac{10Q}{(293)(303)}>0$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is this generated entropy "allowed" to occur in an internally reversible system? What exactly is an internally reversible system?

Comment: It is not.  An internally reversible system is one in which the generated entropy is zero.

Comment: I see. So is an internally reversible system one where there is no viscous dissipation/mixing, and no heat transfers across a finite temperature difference? What then is the difference between an internally reversible and externally reversible system?

Comment: Because the terminology I have been introduced to in my engineering course deals with only "reversible" and "irreversible", and when I asked my prof about whether an ideal Rankine cycle is reversible, he said it was internally reversible. Which prompted me to refer to Cengel and Boles, and hence my confusion about the different classifications of reversibility.

Comment: @V.Jain An ideal Rankiine cycle is a reversible cycle. I am not aware of there being a distinction between internal and external reversibility.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term externally reversible system, but I suppose it can refer to cases where there is viscous dissipation and heat transfer with finite temperature gradients within the surroundings.  Regarding an ideal Rankine cycle, I would say that an ideal cycle is one which is internally reversible (assuming the working fluid is the system).  If you want to get a better understanding of internal reversibility, see Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics by Moran et al.  It seems your understanding of entropy generation mechanisms is correct.

Comment: All right thank you both for your help! @ChetMiller I'll be sure to check out that textbook.